# HTML display div like a tooltip of td

Tags: html, css

I have created a `<div>`, that contains a table inside. The table will be scroll-able vertically. When I mouse over the `<td>` a `<div>` (`.tooltip` in my example) should be display. Here my problem is while showing the `<div>`(`.tooltip`) inside `<td>` it will be displayed without sync. Please help me. Sorry for my bad English.

Here is the code : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Ntn/)

Comment: where you want to display that one?

Comment: like a tool tip of each `<td>` when mouse over... say for example if I mouse over on First `<td>`, then it work fine.. After I scroll my `<div>` it will be misaligned and showing some where in bottom

Comment: yes @web-tiki, you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You just need to add `position:relative;` to your `<td>`

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Ntn/2/)**

**EXPLANATION**

You are using `position: absolute;`  to position your tooltip.

Absolute positioning is relative to the first relatively positioned parent element. As you didn't give any parent element the `position:relative;` property, it is positioned relatively to the last parent (`<html>`) as the `<html>` tag doesn't move with the `.outer` when it is scrolled, the `.tooltip` doesn't move with it.

To correct this, give the relative position to the `<td>` tag so the tooltips are positioned relatively to it and move with it.

More info [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Could you also please explain why it works ? Thanks :)

Comment: @web-tiki It is working good. Thanks for your help. and If any possibility to fix the last `<td>` issue

Comment: Please mouse over the last `<Td>`. The table is jumping

Comment: @MoorthyGK to corect that, you can give some padding-bottom to `.outer` like this : http://jsfiddle.net/k8Ntn/6/

Comment: @MoorthyGK ok I see what you mean by jumping, this issue is only in chrome and is pretty wierd. BUT if you add `box-sizing:border-box;` on the `.tooltip` the table doesn't jump anymore. sse here : http://jsfiddle.net/k8Ntn/14/

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your css:

```
td:hover .tooltip{
 display: block;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
```